# Something is wrong with the loginPagId in community/config/customercommunity.json,please check the value and try again

Tags: salesforcedx, jenkins, deployment-error

I was trying to deploy community site,but then got the above error mentioned in the title,the error tells that value of loginPageId in the json file is not proper, I am not sure what exactly the error is ,even after I tried checking inside the json file,there is a value associated with loginPageId,can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.